# library cbor introduces a new value in the conversion

Tags: node.js, cbor

I made on node.js, this program, which has an anomaly. When I do decodeAllSync I get a vector of decimal numbers
which has one fewer numbers than I get by reconverting the vector with encodeAsync. Why don't I get the same vector?
Thank you

```
const cbor = require('cbor');
...
const results = cbor.decodeAllSync(output);
const input = cbor.encodeAsync(results);
console.log(output);
input.then( 
    function (x) {
      var v=new Uint8Array(x);
      console.log(v);
    },
    function () {
      console.log("fail ");
    });
```

I receive for the printout of the input:

```
Uint8Array [
  129,
  210,
  132,
  77,
  ...
```

I receive for the printout of the output:

```
Uint8Array [
  210,
  132,
  77,
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cbor.decodeAllSync` with n arguments returns an *array* with n entries. So what you encode has an extra pair of `[]` around it.

```
> cbor.decodeAllSync(cbor.encode(1))
[ 1 ]
> cbor.decode(cbor.encode(1))
1
```

Comment: but the encode, it should do it all backwards ... I don't understand ..

Comment: `decodeAllSync` differs from `decode`. See my edited answer.